# Could not find class 'com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM', referenced from method com.whatsapp.App.s

Tags: java, android, android-gallery, android-logcat, whatsapp

I'm Creating a simple custom gallery app. In which I'm showing image in GridView. that's fine but what happened is while I'm checking my logs in Logcat its showing me this also. I don't know why and from where it is coming.

```
12-05 16:45:16.883: E/dalvikvm(22961): Could not find class 'com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM', referenced from method com.whatsapp.App.s
12-05 16:45:16.883: W/dalvikvm(22961): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance  1522 (Lcom/amazon/device/messaging/ADM;) in Lcom/whatsapp/App;
12-05 16:45:16.893: E/dalvikvm(22961): Could not find class 'com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM', referenced from method com.whatsapp.App.w
```

> I'm not doing any thing related to whatsapp or anything, in My Code
>   is this is a Security issue.
>   or its juts a background process of my phone, if it is then please **help me to stop this because it is so annoying**.

Comment: I believe you have whatsapp installed, and the code in whatsapp appears to be logging that it can't find a certain class (android device messaging.) You can filter your log messages to show only those from your application, that might help.